# INSERT INTO SELECT + 1 custom column

Tags: sql

I need to copy data from original table and add custom column specified in query

Original table struct: `col1, col2, col3`

Insert table struct: `x, col1, col2, col3`

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
   SELECT * 
   FROM original 
   WHERE cond
```

and I'm getting this error

> *Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*

HOW can I insert `X` value in this single query?

I tought something like this can pass

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
   SELECT 'x' = NULL, *  
   FROM original 
   WHERE cond
```

Any ideas?

Is it possible to use `*`? Because that table has so many columns and `X` has to be first value

I know this all is bad but I have to edit unbeliveable ugly db with even worse php code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second statement is almost correct, but instead of `'x' = null`, use `null x` (I'm assuming you want to store a `null` value in a column named `x`);

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT null x, o.* FROM original o WHERE cond
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Null as X, *
into newtable
from original
where ...
```

Comment: I'd rather use "*" and it don't work with NULL as first val. Question edited

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT null as x, col1, col2, col3 FROM original WHERE cond
```